# Dropdownlist in MVC3 (asp.net, c#) and submit the selected result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class called Partner, that I need to Submit all the info from the View.

The Drop Down list needs to be filled by a dataset and on submit I want to fill SelectedHeardAboutText with the selected drop down item.

Here is my class:

```
public class Partner
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SelectedHeardAboutText { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> HowDidYouHear { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my PartnerController:

public ActionResult Partner()
    {

```
    var hear = db.HowDidYouHears.ToList();
    var partner = new Partner();
    ViewBag.Hear = hear;

    return View(partner);
}
```

How would I go about creating my drop down on the view, my view model is bassed on the Partner class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedHeardAboutText", 
    new SelectList((IEnumerable<Hear>)ViewBag.Hear, "Value", "Text")
)
```

Obviously that's ugly and I don't recommend it. Don't even know why I am posting it. Probably to say that it should never be used.

Here's the correct way to do it (by using strongly typed view):

```
public ActionResult Partner() 
{
    var partner = new Partner
    {
        HowDidYouHear = db.HowDidYouHears.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Id, // this will be used as value
            Text = x.SomeTextProperty // this will be used as text
        })
    };
    return View(partner);
}
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedHeardAboutText, 
    new SelectList(Model.Hear, "Value", "Text")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<http://dotnetpools.com/Article/ArticleDetiail/?articleId=48&title=Binding%20Dropdownlist%20In%20MVC3%20Using%20C#t;>

## razor ##

    @Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text", Model.CountryList.SelectedValue), new { @id = "ddlist", @data_role = "none", style = "color: #fff; background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #333333; margin-left:3px; width:100%; height:20px;" })


## model ##

     public class somename
      {
       public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
      }
       public class Country
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

## Controller ##

       public ActionResult index()
        {
          List<Country> objcountry = new List<Country>();
          objcountry = GetCountryList();
          SelectList objlistofcountrytobind = new SelectList(objcountry, "ID", "Name", 0);
          model.CountryList = objlistofcountrytobind;       
          return View(model);
        }


      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Analyze(AnalyzeModels model)
       {
          List<Country> objcountry = new List<Country>();
          objcountry = GetCountryList();
          SelectList objlistofcountrytobind = new SelectList(objcountry, "ID", "Name", 0);
          model.CountryList = objlistofcountrytobind;
          return View(model);
       }
              **************************************************
## function for GetCountryList##
        public List<Country> GetCountryList()
        {
            DataTable reportDetailsTable = objCommon.GetDetails("tablename");

            List<Country> objcountrty = new List<Country>();
            int s = reportDetailsTable.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            {
                string d1 = reportDetailsTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                string d2 = reportDetailsTable.Rows[i][10].ToString();
                objcountrty.Add(new Country { ID = d1, LName = d2 });
            }
            return objcountrty;
        }
```